# Impossible to boot after linux-header upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, 17.10, linux-headers

under Ubuntu 17.10, after upgrading to linux-headers 4.13.0-29-generic, I am not able to boot the system anymore.
It gets stuck at the splash screen (Ubuntu logo with 4 dots) and I am not able to see the verbose by pressing ESC.
A few times, a strange message occurred, which I was not able to write it down, but it should be very similar to:
[Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.

I do not know if there is some log I can access to track this down, but if you could give me some instructions, I can give you more info on this.

If I use the older headers (4.13.0-25-generic), I am able to boot again.

Can you help me to solve the issue?

Cheers,
Matteo

Comment: I am getting the same [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer... on Linux Mint 19.  Did you find any pointers to this issue?

Comment: My guess is that there is some incompatibility with the hardware. I moved back to the older headers until a newer version was available; that resolved my problem